# Execute command as if in another open terminal window

Tags: ssh, tty, ps

Let's say I have three Terminal windows open:

1. **ttys001**: the current terminal I am in. Current directory is `~`
2. **ttys002**: current directory is `~/Desktop`
3. **ttys003**: a terminal where I've SSH'd into a remote machine. The current directory on local machine is `~/test`. The current directory of the remote machine is `~/abcdef`

Is it possible to execute a command that runs as if it were in one of the other open terminals, but prints the output in my currently active terminal.

For instance, from **ttys001**, can I get the output of `ls` as if it were run in **ttys002** and have it print in **ttys001**.

Can I also do the same for the remote machine I am connected to in **ttys003** (ie get the output of `ls ~/abcdef` not `ls ~/test`.

Would be interesting in hearing how this would work for macOS and Linux.

Edit:
I am aware I am asking about "terminal windows" as opposed to the processes that are running in them. This is deliberate. The aim is to write a tool that can get the list of files/folders available to a user for each terminal window they have open. If a terminal window is actively SSH'd into another machine, then I'd like to get the files/folders in the working directory of the remote machine.

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. Do you want to `ls` the `~/abcdef` directory on the remote machine? `ssh user@remote_machine 'ls ~/abcdef'`. Try to get the "terminal windows" out of the picture; they have nothing to do with the commands running in them.

Comment: Apologies that it was vague. I added an edit that should hopefully clarify 1. why I am asking about "terminal windows" and 2. the answer to your question

Comment: Also the reason I don't want to do `ssh user@remote_machine 'ls ~/abcdef'` is because I  would need to re-enter the password. Because I am already SSH'd in through another process, I would like to leverage that

Comment: After spending the day investigating this is much more depth, you were right @user414777, my question should be better worded towards process IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `tmux` or `screen`.

You can attach multiple times to a "session", locally, remotely via `ssh`, or in any other way you can start a shell on the machine in question.

Everything that happens in one session will be displayed on all attached terminals.

It is available for MacOS and Linux.